# Proof of the derivative of sine using vectors

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, vector-analysis

I have found a nice proof that the derivative of sine is cosine that uses vectors, but I'm struggling to properly understand it. As $\theta$ increases, the point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ moves around the unit circle. At any given point, the direction of travel is perpendicular to the point's position, and so the rate of change is proportional to $(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$. If $\theta$ is measured in radians, then the proportionality constant is equal to $1$, and we get that
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)
$$
I'm finding this proof difficult to understand because I am unfamiliar with vector calculus. What does the length of the tangent vector represent? E.g. if $\theta$ was measured in degrees, then the rate of change would be
$$
\frac{\pi}{180}(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
$$
So presumably the length of the tangent vector would change, but I don't exactly grasp how. For derivatives, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ tells us the gradient of the tangent to a particular point, but the actual length of the tangent is infinite. So I suppose I am asking about the difference between a tangent and a tangent vector.

Comment: If $\theta$ was measured in degrees the derivative of $\sin\theta$ wouldn't be $\cos\theta$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It would be $\pi / 180 \cos \theta$, however.

Comment: The length of the tangent vector is the speed.  If you change $\theta$ by $a\theta$ speed changes accordingly by a factor $|a|$.

Comment: For the difference between tangent and tangent vector this picture may be of help: https://services.math.duke.edu/education/ccp/materials/mvcalc/vectors/dervec.gif